# How do I find a Specific Game in my Steam Folder?

Tags: 14.04, steam, crouton

I recently downloaded ubuntu 14.04 and a large-ish game via steam.  It's taken up most of my memory (only a gig or so left) and i want to clear unwanted maps from said game by finding it in my steam folder.  I went into it (/.localshare/steam I think?) and wasnt able to find my username in there and therefore couldn't find my game files.  Could anyone give some advice on this please?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

You are correct in the path, you are just not deep enough the path would be

`.local/share/steam/steamapps/common/{name of your game}`

Another way to do it would be to right click on the game name in the list or detailed(not tiled) view of Steams **Library** page the click on  **Properties**  On the window that pops up click on the **Local Files** tab then click on **Browse local files** option.  This will open the game files directly rather than drilling down with the file manager.

From the game files folder you will need to figure out what files you need to delete yourself, it varies from game to game.

If you find that after deleting the files the game does not work properly, you can easily fix this by opening the **Properties** box again and on the local files tab just click on **Verify the Integrity of Game Cache**.  This will check the folder and redownload any missing  files.

You may have to delete the maps every time the game updates, Steam may reinstall them when updating.

Answer (score 0):

Steam folders are hidden in your Home directory. If you press CTRL+H you will see hidden files and folders, as well as the .steam folder.

Your games folder is located in /home/USERNAME/.steam/steam/steamapps

Comment: The .steam/steam folder gets you to the same place as starting in .local, the second "steam" in that path is just a shortcut to the steam folder from the .steam folder.  (your answer is correct,  I just wanted to clarify that it ends in the same folder, just different ways to get there.  I showed the path the way I did b/c the OP had mentioned the path that way)  BTW, the `home/{Username}`  is only needed when you are starting in the root folder, unless you backed up to root, the terminal or nautilus start in your home so the first two steps could be confusing to a newbie